Any proof of $(E+A+\frac{1}{2!}A^2+\cdots)(E+B+\frac{1}{2!}B^2+\cdots)=E+(A+B)+\frac{1}{2!}(A+B)^2+\cdots$ which doesn't use norm of matrices?
I am reading "Linear Algebra" by Ichiro Satake.
Let $A_0,A_1,\dots$ be a sequence of complex $n\times n$ matrices.
We define $A_0+A_1+\cdots$ converges if $a_{ij}^{(0)}+a_{ij}^{(1)}+\cdots$ converges for any $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, where $a_{ij}^{(\nu)}$ is the $(i,j)$ element of $A_{\nu}$.

Let $A$ be a complex $n\times n$ matrix.
Then, $E+A+\frac{1}{2!}A^2+\cdots$ converges.

Let $A$ be a complex $n\times n$ matrix.
Let $B$ be a complex $n\times n$ matrix.
Suppose that $AB=BA$.
Then, $(E+A+\frac{1}{2!}A^2+\cdots)(E+B+\frac{1}{2!}B^2+\cdots)=E+(A+B)+\frac{1}{2!}(A+B)^2+\cdots$ holds.

Satake says the proof of $(E+A+\frac{1}{2!}A^2+\cdots)(E+B+\frac{1}{2!}B^2+\cdots)=E+(A+B)+\frac{1}{2!}(A+B)^2+\cdots$ is the same as the proof of $e^ae^b=e^{a+b}$.
But Satake doesn't define norm of a matrix in this book.
Is there any elementary proof which doesn't use norm of a matrix to prove the above equation?

Ea... Since $AB=BA$ and as the hint shows: let $f(x)=1+x+1/2x^2+\dots$ be the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ then $e^a\times e^b=e^{a+b}$. This identity can be proven by using the binomial coefficients and expanding $(a+b)^k$. You can do the analogous thing to the matrix that commute by multiplication.

@JetfiRex thank you very much.
